# WCF Self Host via https Connection Problems

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, https

I have a WCF web service self hosted within a windows service with Transport security and SSL. There is no Client Authentication.

It looks like its hosing fine. I am able to browse to the service in a web browser if i use the local machine and the address `https://127.0.0.1:9191/Service`

However i cant browse to the service from any other locations using the ip of the hosting machine `https:/10.206.204.21:9191/Service`

Port 9191 and 443 are open in the firewall.

Where do i start to troubleshoot this issue is it network settings or a problem with the code i am using to self host?

Will provide code fragments if required

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Guys Looks like i tracked down the issue.

It was the SSL port binding in netsh.
I had bound the certificate to `ipport=127.0.0.1:9191`

when the binding needed to be done using the actual ip of the machine.
`ipport=10.206.204.21:9191`

Thanks for taking the time to read if you did. Appreciated.